# Django builtin logout redirect is not working _ MDN Tutorial Library

Tags: django

Kindly help me on getting django inbuilt logout page working.
Login is working fine. When I go to logout page. It take me back to admin window, whereas it should go back to login.html page.
So please help me out on sorting what is wrong in the code
So far code is as per MDN tutorial on Local Library

1. locallibrary/urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

2. mdntutorial/templates/registration/login.html

```
directory for your reference is like this
 |_mdntutorial
 |_locallibrary
   |_templates (new)
                |_registration
```

Login.html

```
{% extends "catalog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
  {% endif %}

  {% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
      please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
  </form>

  {# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
  <p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

3. Logout page as per mdn

```
{% extends "catalog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Logged out!</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login'%}">Click here to login again.</a>
{% endblock %}
```

4. settings.py
   These changes added as per instructions from MDN docs.

```
# Redirect to home URL after login (Default redirects to /accounts/profile/)
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,

import os
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/' # or you can set it to any route you want to redirect to after logout
```

right below the

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

setting

Comment: can you mark this as an accepted answer? So that it helps others another time.